# how to show html content when select box item selected

Tags: 7, forms

i have a select box called Delivery method and it has two options Drop off and pick up..,i want to load few extra html fields like size ,pick up address to the page when user select pick up method,what is the best way of doing it drupal..

Comment: You can do this in Drupal, but I think it would be better if you use `show()` and `hide()` extra form fields based on User Input , it will be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In custom form you can use [ajax API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) for this. You can find the sample code from [here](http://drupal.org/project/examples)

When you are using node form then use [conditional_fields](http://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read up on the [FAPI Ajax Framework](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7) in D7? You make a Form using the drupal Form API. It has `#ajax` callbacks that can make use of client-side JS `$commands` to update the DOM clientside.

> When responding to Ajax requests, the server should do what it needs
>   to do for that request, then create a commands array. This commands
>   array will be converted to a JSON object and returned to the client,
>   which will then iterate over the array and process it like a macro
>   language.